# Extract user group while trying to connect using ssh

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line

I have extracted the user name to perform a test:
 `w | grep ^usera | wc -l`

which will show 1 if the `usera` have an open session, but now I need more generic use case to extract user group.

Example: Extract user group , if `group=admin`, then `wc -l` how many users from grp admin have an active session.

Answer (score 1):

You may get the groups that a user belongs to with `id -Gn username`.

To count the number of admins:

```
who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 |
while read user; do
   id -Gn "$user"
done | grep -F -w "admin" | wc -l
```

This uses the `who` command to get a list of logged-in users, extracts the bare username using `cut` and does a group lookup for each of them. Then the groups are grepped for the string `admin` and the result is counted.

Alternatively, do it backwards by seeing if an admin is logged in:

```
who $( awk -F':' '$1 ~ /^admin/ { gsub(",", " ", $4); print $4 }' /etc/group ) | wc -l
```

The `awk` in inside the command substitution will output all the users that belong to the `admin` group, and the `who` will see if they are logged in. The number of lines of output from this is then counted.

Comment: Thanks, this is very usefull - actually I want to test also the group of the user trying to authenticate: Example: if user a trying to authenticate is member of group developers => then I test if a member of grp admin is logged in.

Comment: @OussemaBenlagha That's a totally different question.